# Form doesn't work when submit button is in the modal window

Tags: html, forms

I have HTML form with submit button inside. Inside the form there are piece of HTML code which popups in modal window when filling up the form. Inside this modal are one more input and submit button. And it does not work, the form doesn't send to email. But when I move entire button HTML code right before `</form>` then submit button works. Here is a code:

```html
<form name="autoForm" id="contact-form" class="row" method="post" action="php/send.php">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label id="address-label" for="place">* Markė | modelis | metai | TA | miestas</label>
    <input id="form_place" type="text" name="place" class="form-control" data-error="Laukas privalomas" >
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="message">Automobilio būklė</label>
    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control h-auto" rows="4" data-error="Prašau, parašykite daugiau apie NT" 
    placeholder="Čia galite parašyti daugiau informacijos apie automobilio būklę"></textarea>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="submit-container col mt-5">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="to-modal-form"><font size="4">Sužinoti kainą</font></a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="modal-background" class="modal-background container-hidden">
    <div id="modal-form" class="modal-form">
      <a id="modal-close"><i class="icon-close" data-v-27b8b94e=""></i></a>
      <div class="form-header">
        <h2>Gaukite kainos pasiūlymus tiesiai į savo telefoną.</h2>
        <p>Įveskite telefono numerį ir gaukite pasiūlymo nuorodą <b>SMS</b></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-body">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="phone" for="phone">* Jūsų telefono numeris</label>
        <input id="form_phone" type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Laukas privalomas">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="code" value="" id="code" />
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="form_submit"><font size="4">Tęsti</font></button>
      <span class="privacy">Sutinku su <a href="">privatumo politika</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Filling up first inputs there are first button `<a class="btn btn-primary" id="to-modal-form"><font size="4">Sužinoti kainą</font></a>` which is opening the modal windows. Inside after filling up additional input I press `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="form_submit"><font size="4">Tęsti</font></button>` which doesn't work.
But form work when button is moved before `</form>`. Form sends all values - inside and out of modal window.
Can't get what is wrong.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the button really part of another `<form>` element in the DOM?

Comment: @NicoHaase I think it is the modal functionality, often the libraries implementing this move the actual modal container to a different position in the DOM. There is only one form here, but the button has been moved outside of it by the client-side scripting that initializes the modal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved this by adding submit button before  with attribute `hidden`:

```html
<form>
  <!-- the form content -->

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="form_submit"  hidden></button>
</form>
```

And that button inside of modal window made as trigger with attribute `onclick="submitForm();"` like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm();"><font size="4">Tęsti</font></button>
```

In JS it triggers submit button using `.click()` method:

```js
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('form_submit');

function submitForm() {
  submitBtn.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have button outside `</form>` it would not work the solution is using `form=""` parameter to the `button` it basically tell this `button` belong to this specific `form` element

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" form="contact-form" type="submit" id="form_submit"><font size="4">Tęsti</font></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It's the best one i've got to solve this problem. Your solution should me marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button will confused which form that it should submitted if you place it outside the form tag.

You could use javascript to submit the form.
https://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit/

Put a button inside your modal with `onclick="submitForm('contact-form');"`, then add below js code

```
function submitForm(id) {
     document.getElementById(id).submit();
}
```

Comment: You should see his question `But when I move entire button HTML code right before </form> then submit button works`

Comment: @ZaidYasyaf I think you're half-right here. The issue is that the button is not part of the form - only the _reason_ for that is not the initial HTML, but that the library that implements the modal functionality, took the modal element out of the form and moved it elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: Solved this by adding submit button before `</form>` with attribute `hidden`, and that button inside of modal window made as trigger with attribute `onclick="submitForm();"`. In Js it triggers submit button using `click()` method. Thank you everyone.